# TypeInitializationException when initializing a Subclass with a Dependency Property

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have the following simple **TextBox subclass**, which **adds one dependency property** (OutputIndex):

```
public class OutputTextBox : TextBox
{
    public OutputTextBox() : base() { }

    public int OutputIndex
    {
        get { return (int)this.GetValue(OutputIndexProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(OutputIndexProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutputIndexProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "OutputIndex", 
      typeof(int), 
      typeof(OutputTextBox), 
      new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

When I try to instantiate an instance of OutputTextBox, like

```
OutputTextBox otb = new OutputTextBox();
```

I get a **System.TypeInitializationException** thrown with the InnerException saying: "**Default value type does not match type of property 'OutputIndex'.**"

What **'Default value type'** is the InnerException referring to? What do I need to do to be able to instantiate an instance of OutputTextBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *PropertyMetadata* is set to initialize OutputIndex with a default value of **false**. False is a boolean, OutputIndex is an int, hence the type exception.

Pass an integer argument to *PropertyMetadata*, or leave it blank for no default value.

Comment: Of course - thanks! 

That's what I get for doing cut and paste without reading the documentation in detail.